# How short can a Scrum Sprint be?

Tags: continuous-integration, scrum, continuous-deployment

Based on [this Scrum Sprint description](http://scrummethodology.com/scrum-sprint/), Sprints are known to be 30 days long, but can be as short as one week.  How does this fit with continuous deployment.  With CD you release completed stories right after they pass integration.

Is it possible to have a 2 week sprint, but instead of "delivering" the completed stories at the end of the sprint, you just show that they are already delivered?  You may have actually released them throughout the sprint.

The problem is that integrating and releasing throughout the sprint doesn't let the team plan out the sprint.  It allows management to push the team to release release release, cut corner, and push out code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the Sprint, the Team needs to come to an agreement with the Product Owner which items they will produce during the Sprint (whatever the length).  This happens in the Sprint planning meeting, which is called that for a reason (PLANNING is involved).

During the Sprint, the team delivers the promised items--if they promised to integrate items and put them into prod, that's what they do.  There's nothing inherent to Scrum that says when items can or cannot go into prod--it's up to the Team and the Product Owner.

A basic idea in Scrum is that nobody outside the Team (including the Product Owner) is allowed to change which items the Team will work on during a Sprint, once it has started.

Comment: If the team takes a story, implements it, and deploys it according to the definition of done, then gets another story, and does it again, and again, then what is the purpose of a sprint.  I'm not trying to be rude, but agile is about doing what matters, and adapting.  I don't see how the sprint matters, unless it just serves as a delivery date for a story.

Comment: If the sprint has more then one story in it, and a length of time, who decides the order to do the stories?  With CD, it might make sense to use a decision matrix - critical to the business, complexity to implement, and do the highly critical / easy stuff first, and generally do all the highly critical before the lessor critical, in general.  Seems to me like to producing stories, and scrum sprints don't help much.

Comment: The purpose of the Sprint is that it gives the team some safety--during the sprint, a manager cannot come and say "don't do that, this is much more important" one day, and then come back and contradict the prioritization the next day.  The priorities set at the BEGINNING of the sprint, during the Planning Meeting, and what the team can safely work with for the duration of the Sprint.

The Product Backlog is managed by the Product Owner, and it should establish the priority of the backlog items (which may be user stories). She definitely could use sort of matrix you describe when doing so.

Comment: To clarify my last statement--the team should be pulling ALL the product backlog items it thinks it can accomplish during the sprint during the planning meeting.  It's not just taking the top one, seeing how it goes, and then taking another. Among other things, this helps give the team a sense of urgency--it has agreed to complete a certain number of things in 2 weeks--now it must deliver!  The set timeboxes also makes velocity apparent, so that you can reliably predict how long it will take to complete the project.

Comment: It may be that you feel you've reduced signifantly or (impossible, but lacking a better word) eliminated the complexity from your development efforts.  The things you are producing are relatively similar.  Sprints provide a number of things, but among them are managing risk and maintaining predictability.

Answer (score 0):

If *Done* means in production, ship it.

Why can the team not plan?  They know that shipping is part of the done criteria for any PBI and, as such, the sizing and planning of the Sprint regardless of length should take this into account.

There always exists the chance that management will push for a faster pace at the expense of the team's definition of done, but the team, Scrum Master, and Product Owner (Scrum Team) are obligated to work with management to solve the source of that push.

Comment: This has turned into a fantastic discussion on the Scrum.org trainers list.  I'll post the results here.  I'm hopeful Ken will chime in.

Comment: could you could send a link to make that plug of scrum.org more credible?

Comment: It's not a public mailing list sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the result of the discussion on Scrum.org trainer list (so far, I'm sure others will respond).  I must say I agree with what was said on the list and find fault in my previous answer as I had forgotten a very important angle on a simple point.

As you might recall though many don't, a Sprint is expected to have an overarching, somewhat fuzzy goal.  Many or most, but not all, Product Backlog Items exist in reaching the goal.  The easy example I often use is: We want to Increase the Social Networking presence of our application.  PBIs may range from showing a Twitter feed, to Liking products, and some Google+ integratione, etc.

The goal gives both a guiding light to why we are building these things, but it also allows the business and team wiggle room in deciding if a sprint was a success if we are unable to complete some of the PBIs.  For instance, if we complete the Twitter feed and Facebook Like integration, but unforeseen API stability issues keep us from solving Google+ integration the business may still find success in the sprint because we have in fact "Increased the Social Networking presence" in our app.

This is an easy and natural angle to take as team members, because it gives us an out.  Something we are always desperate for by habit in our high pressure environments.  The really important angle is from the perspective of the business and I forget this being a coder by trade.

If we ship the Twitter feed when it is done, then ship the Facebook integration when it is done, but then fail on the Google+ integration it may be that the business feels we've missed the mark.  Now this is a contrived example, but think of it as something very important like a multi-channel marketing campaign with Sweepstakes, Online games, Text message lottery, etc.  Missing one or more of these could mean the **business** opportunity has passed, because they revolve around the Olympics or something.  Businesses do work in this manner.

A continuous flow model might be great, because they see things happening when they never used to, but it's not what Scrum is aiming for which is providing the business with a well oiled machine with a cadence.

Comment: Wikipedia says, "Scrum is ... often seen in agile software development".  And the 1st principal of the agile manifesto describes CD as core to agile:  "Our highest priority is to satisfy the customer
through early and continuous delivery of valuable software."   So, is it true some of my previous workmates would respond if someone asked if we were agile.  "We aren't agile, we're scrum."

Comment: Don't stop at the first principal... the 3rd: "Deliver working software frequently, from a couple of weeks to a couple of months, with a preference to the shorter timescale."  I totally get what you're saying though.  Continuous deployment is certianly a form of continuous delivery and one that accentuates the vigilance of high quality and feedback.  Continuous flow Scrum has been discussed by Jeff Sutherland (page 111 here http://www.crisp.se/scrum/books/ScrumPapers20070424.pdf).  I do with I could relay the transcript of the email chain, but I'll have to ask the members.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is No.  The process model you are describing is more like Kanban than Scrum.  With Kanban, the team releases items as soon as they pass through the final stage - in your case this is the Integration stage.  With Scrum, the PO has to decide at the end of the sprint whether to release the increment or not.  Releasing items mid-sprint is not a best practice in Scrum.

Comment: Thanks for this reply.  So by this definition, Scrum and CD are incompatible.  Is there a book or site you'd recommend I look at to further understand these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I feel I now understand that Scrum is not agile, in the sense that continuous deployment is core to agile, and Scrum is about a cadence of release points about 1 - 4 weeks part with a product owner that decides at the end of the sprint, not in a continuous mid-sprint manner.

In fact, wikipedia states that "Scrum is ... often seen in agile software development", implying not always, and certainly not synonymous.

I suppose pre-released software development, or non server based software that has a natural release cycle could be agile to the point that CI is done, and still be managed with Scrum.

Scrum is just between Waterfall and Agile, then.  Much better then Waterfall, and closer to Agile, but not Agile.

Waterfall:  few big long sprints
Scrum:  managed smaller sprints
Agile:  continuous sprinting